# custom bundle file name angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3 to bundle the project files. When i run ng build, it creats main.bundle.js file under dist folder.

Instead of main.bundle.js I want to give a custom name (example: myproject.js). Is there a way to provide a custom output file name when using ng build.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately no, the bundle names cannot be configurable. There is no option for such thing in the build wiki: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

however, you can run a simple nodejs script to do that for you:

```
// rename.js file - location, right next to package.json
var fs = require("fs");
fs.rename("./dist/main.bundle.js", "./dist/myproject.js");
```

then in your package.json, add a new `script` call it something like `build-rename`

```
"scripts":{
   "build-rename":"ng build && node rename.js"
}
```

now run the script `npm run build-rename`