# is it possible to configure the filenames generated by cli ng build --prod?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to configure the js bundle filenames generated by CLI? "ng build --prod" outputs files with names like this to the dist dir:

- inline.cb2534b55477f6dd88f2.bundle.js
- main.81e08a23f86e34690c6c.bundle.js
- polyfills.b1706c7adb46ed3216b9.bundle.js
- vendor.c60c1fef7e91c2217820.bundle.js

I have a requirement to use the app's current build number as the second part of the filename.  So if the app build number is 1.15.2 then the dist js filenames would look like this:  inline.1.15.2.bundle.js

Do you know if "ng build --prod" supports a flag to configure the second part of the output filename?  Or will I most likely need to create some type of custom post-build routine which programatically makes this update?

Comment: I don't think this is achievable via the CLI itself. You can use `--output-hashing none` to turn off the hashing completely but that seems to be as far as it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `hash` part with output-hashing option on ng build --prod

> output-hashing
>   --output-hashing (aliases: -oh)
>
> Define the output filename cache-busting hashing mode.
>
> Values: none, all, media, bundles

[Docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Comment: I don't see a way to change the default filename of inline.cb2534b55477f6dd88f2.bundle.js to a custom filename of inline.1.15.2.bundle.js by using the --output-hashing flag.  If you know how to do this then will you please reply with the full cmd?

Comment: I didn't test yet, but this seems to at least help (like a batch) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258641/5468463

Answer (score 1):

You can just write script to rename files after build, depending on your operational system. Or use [npm rename package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rename).

Comment: yeah I know I can write a custom post-build routine. that's my default option but was just wondering if there's a more configurable/integrated way to do this via the cli

Comment: "npm rename package" is an interesting option but how would I implement that based on looping through files in a dir and replacing the part between the second and third dots with a custom value?

Comment: something like this rename({
  basename: 'main',
  extname: '.js',
  hash: 'yout hash'
}, {
  basename: 'main',
})