# How to remove hash from a particular bundle file name, on creating prod build in angular 10

Tags: angular, webpack, google-chrome-extension, webpack-4, angular10

I am trying to create a chrome extension using angular 10. On doing ng build --prod, hash is getting appended in the background.js bundle file like "background.6f24e1b6d7ac365xxxxx.js".

**Is there a way I can remove the hash only for this bundle on doing ng build --prod?.**

One thing I can do is renaming of this file using node as mentioned in [custom bundle file name angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257694/custom-bundle-file-name-angular-cli). I am looking to achieve this via webpack or in any other way.

**custom.webpack.config** file (Needed this to copy manifest.json to dist folder and to transpile background.ts to background.js as it is not being using in the angular app)

```
const CopyWebPackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebPackPlugin({
            patterns:[
            {from:'manifest.json', to:''}            
            ]
        }),
      ]
    entry: { background: 'src/background.ts' } 
}
```

**manifest.json** file for google chrome extension

```
{
    "name": "Javascript",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "javascript",
    "key": <chrome extension key>,
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "signin.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "./background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "identity"
    ]
}
```

**background.ts** file

```
This will contain code for google chrome extension in typescript or javascript
```

**Note:** I want to this only for two bundle runtime.js and background.js. I want to keep hashing in other bundles like main.xxxxxxxxxx.js, polyfills.xxxxxxxxxx.js, polyfills-es5.xxxxxxxxxx.js etc.

Comment: why would you want to do that? JS files with the same name are cached by the client's browser. Hashes help to ensure that your files are up-to-date and cached with other files correctly.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. @pixelbits. As I mentioned, I am creating a google chrome extension, which need manifest.json file. In that file we need to mention the name of the js file which will run in background. If the name of the file changes with each build then I need to manually update manifest.json with the new file name after every prod build. I want to avoid this manual process. Although I know that prod build will not be very frequent but still.